# Multi Device Hybrid App for Windows Phone: How to set the logo?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to figure out, how to set the app logo as well as the splashscreen using the preview for cordova apps (or Multi-Device Hybrid Apps) in Visual Studio 2013. I tried adding

```
<platform name="wp8">
  <icon src="img/logo.png" width="99" height="99" />
  <!-- tile image -->
  <icon src="img/logo.png" width="159" height="159" />
</platform>
```

However this won't do the trick. It's a pretty new thing so finding informations on this topic is kind of hard. It was pretty easy, using the old method. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-Device Hybrid apps use the Cordova CLI to build for each platform, which provides a fallback by default, so you don't actually need to add a reference in your HTML files.

Instead, to set a logo (I assume you're talking about the icon that shows up in the app drawer), you need to add(or replace) the image in res/icons/wp8/ by following the resolution and naming guidelines mentioned in ["Platform-specific Visual Assets"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#VisualAssets) section of the docs.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was somewhere in the docs - haven'T found it though.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to wp8.1 emulator instead of wp8 emulator.