# Where do you set app properties normally specified in the appmanifest file?

Tags: cordova, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to change

- the name of the splash screen file for Windows 8 app
- the background colour. It is set to dark grey currently.

Can't find it anywhere in the config.xml

Those are normally set in the .appxmanifest file

Comment: Why can't you use the .appxmanifest?

Comment: Can I? And if I can do I place it in the merges folder?

Comment: config.xml duplicates certain fields already contained in the .appxmanifest so I assumed I can't use it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm not an app developer.  I just was wondering if there was a simpler problem to solve ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set platform specific assets ( like the logo for instance), you need to add(or replace) the image in res/icons/windows8/ by following the resolution and naming guidelines mentioned in the [Platform-specific Visual Assets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#VisualAssets) section of the MDHA documentation.

MDHA uses the cordova CLI to build for each platform. Your platform specific .appxmanifest will be overwritten every time a build happens. Therefore, it is not advisable to make changes to the manifest directly.

This has also been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25193978/3900092

**EDIT**

To set the background color for your splash screen, you need to set the `BackgroundColor` preference in the `config.xml` file

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>
```

This will set the property within the `<VisualElements>` tag.

If you need to set this for a particular platform, encapsulate the preference within a platform tag as documented at [Per platform configuration (config.xml) on cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825634/per-platform-configuration-config-xml-on-cordova)

Comment: Thank you. Your post does not answer my question unfortunately. I already knew what you wrote about. How do you for instance set a background colour of a splashscreen? At the moment it just defaults to dark grey

Comment: I.e. this one. See background color set to grey `<VisualElements BackgroundColor="#464646" Description="" ...  </VisualElements>`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Just a suggestion - you may want to drop your example in your docs. It is not that obvious to someone new to PhoneGap/Corodova ...